# Airflow 2.0, Could not build url for endpoint 'Airflow.legacy_graph'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/dags.html", line 44, in top-level template code
{% elif curr_ordering_direction == 'asc' and request.args.get('sorting_key') == attribute_name %}
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/main.html", line 21, in top-level template code
{% from 'airflow/_messages.html' import show_message %}
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/baselayout.html", line 2, in top-level template code
{% import 'appbuilder/baselib.html' as baselib %}
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/init.html", line 12, in top-level template code
{% block head_meta %}
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/dags.html", line 63, in block 'head_meta'

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 370, in url_for
with_categories: bool = False, category_filter: t.Iterable[str] = ()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2216, in handle_url_build_error
subdomain = None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 357, in url_for
# always in sync with the session object, which is not true for session
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 2179, in build
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'Airflow.legacy_graph'. Did you mean 'Airflow.graph' instead?`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

While starting the Airflow webserver, get Airflow.legacy_graph error.
Let me know, how can we resolve such kind of error?